# dropzonejs y tiempo de espera para subir una foto

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Estoy utilizando dropzone y tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<form class="dropzone dz-clickable dz-started" method="post" action="comprueba.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="footdrop">
<input style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;" class="dz-hidden-input" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file">

</div>
<div id="footenviar" align="center">    
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" class="boton" />
</div>
     <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="<?php echo $ref ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="revisado" value="0">
     <input type="hidden" name="subida" value="1">
</form>
```

Cuando arrastro un archivo si espero poco tiempo al darle al submit no me sube el archivo, creo que a la cache del navegador no le da tiempo a cargarlo.
¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 2):

Viendo la [documentacion](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#dropzone-methods), una solución sería desactivar el botón submit en el evento `addedfile`, y volver a activarlo en el evento `complete`